# Should I use the plural, or the singular, with "none"?

Tags: plural-forms

In Italian, the equivalent of *none* is *nessuno* (or *nessuna*), which is never used as plural, nor does it have a plural form.

When I use *none* in English, should I use the singular (e.g. "none of them is perfect"), the plural (e.g. "none of them are perfect"), or both are correct?

Comment: kiam, "use the plural verb when the _of_-phrase finishes with a plural noun" Jespersen says in "A Modern English Grammar".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Idiomatic English accepts both "none are" and "none is" as [grammatically correct](http://alt-usage-english.org/excerpts/fxnoneis.html). Not everyone agrees. If Barrie answers this question, I'm sure he'll point out that *CGEL* supports both usages. I do too, and I use whichever I feel is appropriate for the particular sentence I'm writing or editing. You cannot say "neither are" but must say "neither is" because it's disjunctive, but "none" is a collective as well as a collection of individuals, as in "the team are demoralized" (BrE) and "the team is demoralized" (AmE).

["None **are** more hopelessly enslaved than **those** who falsely believe **they are** free." Johann Wolfgang von Goethe](http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/quotes/j/johannwolf134023.html). Obviously a translation from German into English, but look at the words in bold. This is grammatical and idiomatic English.

The *[Oxford Dictionary](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/none)* online has a usage note about the singular versus plural controversy: both are grammatical.

Comment: You say not everyone agrees; over which usage would there be disagreement?  Mass nouns used with "none" are conjugated as singular, while count nouns are conjugated as plural except in cases where the only alternative to "none" would be "one".  "Which one of the Howard brothers *appears* [singular conjugation] in the middle of a Three Stooges title card?  None of them *does* [also singular]--Larry Fine appears there."